# How can I use an fstream object as a member variable?

Tags: c++, io, fstream

Previously, I would pass the address of fstream objects to any functions, including the constructor, that do I/O operations. But I want to try making fstream objects available as member variables so that all subsequent I/O operations can use those variables instead of having them passed as arguments.

Consider the following Java program:

```
public class A {
    Scanner sc;

    public A(Scanner read) {
        sc = read;
    }
}
```

What would be the C++ equivalent of this? I tried doing this

```
class A {
    ofstream *out;

    public:
        A (ofstream &output) {
            out = output;
        }
};
```

But this gives me a compilation error:

> [Error] invalid user-defined conversion from 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream}' to 'std::ofstream* {aka std::basic_ofstream*}' [-fpermissive]

Comment: You can't assign a reference to a pointer. Those are different things.

Comment: _"But this gives me a compilation error."_ Be specific about compilation errors. Post a [MCVE] please!

Comment: Also you're asking for output, not for input like _scanner_ would imply.

Comment: you're right, but I was asking for general I/O operations. It didn't matter to me which one I used. As for the compilation error, I will edit my original post to include it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest use of a reference type as the member variable of the class.

```
class A {
    ofstream& out;

    public:
        A (ofstream &output) : out(output) {}
};
```

It is cleaner than using a pointer.

If you want objects of type `A` to read data from a stream (like the name `Scanner` suggests), use a `std::istream`.

```
class A {
    std::istream& in;

    public:
        A (std::istream &input) : in(input) {}
};
```

Comment: I just noticed the OP barks up the completely wrong tree. They want input, not output.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, good call. Fortunately, the same principle applies to an `istream` also.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Could you please explain why "A (ofstream &output) : out(output) {}" works but

A (ofstream &output) {
    out = output;
}

doesn't? When I try the latter, it gives me an "uninitialized reference member 'A::out' [-fpermissive]" error. Why doesn't the former cause the same error?

Comment: A reference must be initialized using the member initialization list. It's similar to initializing reference variables in a function. You can't use `int i; int& ref; ref = i;`. You have to use `int i; int& ref = i;`.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want

```
class A {
    ofstream *out;

    public:
        A (ofstream &output) : out(&output) {
                                // ^ Take the address
        }
};
```

---

Since `std::ofstream` is specialized for files, the even better interfacing would be:

```
class A {
    ostream *out;

    public:
        A (ostream &output) : out(&output) {
        }
};
```

Thus you could use your class transparently for non file oriented output targets as well, like

```
A a(std::cout); // writes to standard output rather than using a file
```